# Brainstorming ways to water seal a submarine with a protruding instrument?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics, waterproofing

I am currently working on a submarine that has a flat face at one end made of 1/2" acrylic. Currently, there is a 12mm glass sensor that protrudes through a hole in the acrylic face and I am looking for a way to seal the hole to withstand around 200 psi, however finding a way to seal the face with o-rings has been incredibly challenging, along with finding a seal that wide. I have explored rubber grommets, cable glands, and potentially making a custom mount for the seal and was wondering if there are any instruments that would accomplish my goal. Thank you!

Comment: I was going to suggest cable glands. Why did they not work? Is the sensor cylindrical surface smooth?

Comment: I actually have just decided to go with a cable gland I found from Digikey. I was having the frustrating challenge of finding a cable gland from various manufacturers where they didn't state the pressure rating. However, all of the ones on Digikey have excellent documentation. Thank you!